# Cloud-sql-proxy go binary returns 404

Tags: google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to run `cloud_sql_proxy` installed as a binary from `go get`, but I always get a 404 Error.

I have followed the instructions at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy, but with no luck.

`$GOPATH/go/bin/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=project_name:region:instance_name=tcp:3306 -credential_file=/path/to/cloud-sql-proxy.json`

The error I get:

```
2020/01/18 13:20:03 Rlimits for file descriptors set to {&{8500 9223372036854775807}}
2020/01/18 13:20:03 using credential file for authentication; email=<EMAIL>
2020/01/18 13:20:03 errors parsing config:
    googleapi: got HTTP response code 404 with body: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/sql/v1beta4/sql/v1beta4/projects/project_name/instances/instance_name?alt=json&amp;prettyPrint=false</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

However, if I get the binary from https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy, then the connection if fine, proving that the instance address and the credential file work just fine. The service account has also the Cloud SQL Admin role, so that should be just fine as well.

I have cloned the repo, and tried to debug the code to see where exactly if fails, and of course, it fails at:

```
cmd/cloud_sql_proxy/proxy.go:268

    sql.BasePath = *host
    inst, err := sql.Instances.Get(proj, name).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return instanceConfig{}, err
    }
```

The reason I am insisting on using the go-binary is that I want to re-use cloud_sql_proxy on Raspberry PI 3b+, and this seems to be the only option of getting cloud_sql_proxy working on ARM architecture.

Comment: The hostname seems missing in the error message, the url start directly with `/sql/v1beta4...`. Can you check this config?

Comment: I debugged it further, and the GET request does set the proper host, and calls: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/sql/v1beta4/projects/{project_name}/instances/{instance_name}`

Comment: It appears to be just a bug introduced by latest commits in the repo. If I just checkout v1.16, it works fine.